# OpenCV to detect movement

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, vision

This may be a repost but I thought I might open a topic myself since nothing really answers my questions so far.

Okay, so if I attach a webcam to a robot, is it possible to use the webcam to determine which way the robot is moving (Forward, back, turning left, turning right) because I am doing a project that requires me to detect alignment of the robot down a hallway using a webcam.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [optical flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow). It is implemented in [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)